# Prepare SUM function for the given dynamic string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Given string:

**Note**: The following comma separted string is dynamic which comes with any combination.

```
DECLARE @Str varchar(max) = '[A-B],[B-C],[C-D],[D-E]'
```

**Expected Result**:

```
SUM([A-B]) AS [A-B],SUM([B-C]) AS [B-C],SUM([C-D]) AS [C-D],SUM([D-E]) AS [D-E]
```

My try:

```
SELECT 'SUM('+REPLACE(@Str,',','),SUM(')+')'
```

Output:

```
SUM([A-B]),SUM([B-C]),SUM([C-D]),SUM([D-E])
```

Comment: This just seems like a bad idea in the first place; it's an injection issue just waiting to happen. I think we would be better off if you started from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being SQL Server 2008 you would first need to create an SplitString function (it's already included in SQL Server 2016 and forward), like this one :

[T-SQL split string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string)

Then you can calculate your clauses :

```
select 'sum(' + Name + ', as ' + Name
from SplitString(@Str)
```

And finally you only need to concatenate all those rows, for example adding for xml path('')

```
select 'sum(' + Name + ', as ' + Name + ','
from SplitString(@Str)
for xml path('')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
DECLARE @Str AS TABLE ([Str] varchar(max) )
INSERT INTO @Str
SELECT  '[A-B],[B-C],[C-D],[D-E]' 


;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT  'SUM( '+Split.a.value('.','nvarchar(100)')+' ) AS 'AS [Str],Split.a.value('.','nvarchar(100)') AS [Str1]

FROM
(
SELECT  CAST('<S>'+(REPLACE([Str],',','</S><S>')+'</S>') AS XML ) AS [Str]
FROM @Str
)AS A
CROSS APPLY [Str].nodes('S') AS Split(a)
)

SELECT  STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', '+ CONCAT([Str], [Str1])
FROM CTE 
FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') AS ExpectedResult
```

Result

```
ExpectedResult
-------------------
 SUM( [A-B] ) AS [A-B], SUM( [B-C] ) AS [B-C], SUM( [C-D] ) AS [C-D], SUM( [D-E] ) AS [D-E]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to achieve your task

```
    Declare @str varchar(max) = '[A-B],[B-C],[C-D],[D-E]'
        , @Main varchar(max)=''


        select  @Main += ',sum('+a+')'
         from (select distinct value as a from STRING_SPLIT(@str , ',')) as Splt 
        set @Main= stuff(@Main ,1,1,'')
        print @Main

Result : sum([A-B]),sum([B-C]),sum([C-D]),sum([D-E])
```

Comment: String_Split is only available since SQL Server 2016, and OP is using SQL Server 2008.